# Migrating comments of recipe module from D6 to D7

Tags: 7

Hi I have a site which teaches how to cook different types of food and I use recipe module for listing the recipes of different foods. The site was first developed in Drupal6 and recently I have migrated the site to Drupal7. I used the options in recipe module to export all the recipes in my D6 site to import in Drupal7 and was success. Now I need to migrate all the comments made by the users for each recipe to D7. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure if it belongs here. Modules should provide either import-export or upgrade path. This one clearly did it, but not for comments. Shouldn't your question be a feature request? OK, more important questions: do you have a d6 instance up and alive? Do you know if convents are built in ones forced to work with recipes or custom ones? It later, have you found out how are they stored in database?